# Fetching plain text in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes, plaintext

I have a Yahoo pipe taking the Atom feed from a Google group, and I want to do some processing on the message's full text (running various regular expressions to extract data). I can get a message's text in plain text from from Google using a url like this:

```
http://groups.google.com/group/(group_name)/msg/(message_id)?dmode=source&output=gplain
```

However, I'm having trouble getting it inside Yahoo pipes as a string value. Fetch Page rejects non-HTML pages. YQL using the html table seems to work, and wraps the plain text inside a p element, whose text I can extract like this:

```
select * from html where url="..." and xpath="//p"
```

However, if the message text contains html tags, YQL returns an HTML subtree instead of a string. Is there any way of flattening it back into its HTML source?

Comment: Can you post the link to the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to remove the "output=gplain" and grab the content from the pre element.

```
select content from html 
where url="http://groups.google.com/group/haml/msg/0f78eda2f5ef802d?dmode=source" 
and xpath='//div[contains(@class,"maincontbox")]/pre'
```

I have created a pipe with Google Group and Message ID as inputs to demonstrate:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=3d345e162405e7dbd47d73b95c21f102

Comment: I tried clicking the "Get as JSON" link, and the `<abbr title="English">` tag is missing from the post text.

Comment: Hmm. Fetch data seems to be removing elements. [This pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=0d78444a7ef1e414fc483151c5c0981b) shows how the result from Fetch Data is different from just entering the url in your browser, particularly the abbr is missing as you mentioned.